# import gdal, return "ImportError: DLL load failed:"

Tags: python, gdal, installation, dll

I came up against this problem during the installation of gdal, I tried several solutions already read on the site but none helped me. Here's what I did:

```
1) uninstall gdal
2) uninstall Anaconda
3) install Anaconda
4) conda create new env("GDAL")
5) (GDAL) conda install conda-forge gdal
```

[image]

What am I supposed to do?

Comment: This error message usually means that you have installed a gdal version that is incompatible with one of its (C) dependencies. If you use conda for version management, it would probably be best to reinstall gdal in a new environment and use that environment.

Answer (score -1):

with `cmd` go to the `pip` folder, under

> C:\Python37\Scripts

and then

```
pip install gdal
```

[image]